# Calling client script for form validation from Suitelet in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a Suitelet , basically a form with 'Start date' and 'End date' fields. I want to check for validation of the values entered by user using Client Script in that Suitelet.

Answer (score 1):

1. Attach the Client Script to the Form via `Form.clientScriptModulePath`
2. Implement the `validateField` entry point in the Client Script.

Comment: hey @erictgrubaugh the linking is working fine now..I am not stuck in ClientScript part..I would be thankful if you could look into this....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64301854/client-script-for-form-validation-not-working